# Select@all for document UNID in notes not showing all documents

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I created a view to retrieve all document UNID in lotus notes. The view selection formula is select@all. The total no.of documents in nsf is 1200 but the view shows 1198 documents what about the other 2 documents. As per my analysis there is no deleted or profile documents present. How to retrieve those two documents please advice. Thanks

Comment: Have you switched of showing responses in a hierarchy in the view properties? The two documents are most probably replication conflicts…

Comment: How do you know they are not profile documents? Download and install NotesPeek, it'll help you inspect the database.

Comment: @TorstenLink the issue solved once i uncheck showing response document hierarchy. i have the DB in local only then how does it occur replication conflicts

Comment: It is called "Save & Replication conflict". They can occur within one replica if a document is saved from different functions at the same time (e.g. backend "save" in agent while you have the document open), no need for a replica to create conflicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every view in a Notes Database has an option called "Organizing response documents in a hierarchy" that is enabled by default.

That means that documents that do not have a parent document are not shown in these views. In addition reponses might be "invisible" in the view as they are shown "indented" but collapsed without a visible indicator to expand the hierarchy and show the missing documents.

Disabling this view property makes the documents visible again. They might be "real" responses or probably Save / Replication conflicts that occur if one document is saved in two different places at the same time (these places might even be within the same database replica).

Another possibility for "invisible" documents are documents that are protected by reader fields. They are counted to the document count of the database but not visible to you due to your name missing in the reader field.

Comment: Thank you for your response. after unchecking the response document hierarchy for one NSF i got all document UNID but for another NSF there is no author/ reader field and there is no ACL Roles present but the total count of documents is mismatched in the all document UNID view. i tried with SELECT @ ALL & @AllDescendants as view selection formula. still not able to get the total no.of document. Please help to resolve

Comment: Make a categorized view, categorized by unid, create a column with formula ```1``` and enable total... enable "show empty categories"... Does the total count match? then you have documents that HAVE reader fields... b.t.w: SELECT @All already includes everything, no need for & @AllDescendants...

Comment: thanks a lot. now the the total count is matched may i know the reason why does the previous option doesn't work?

Comment: Now Expand all... you will find at least one "Empty" category, where you see the category but not the document in it... as said: it is reader field protected... you need Full Admin Access to see this document...